# Why are my delegate methods never called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, delegates, master-detail

I've tried to set up a very basic delegate between a `TableViewController` and a `DetailViewController`, but the methods are never called. Here's my code:

**DetailViewController.h**

```
@protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate

- (void) detailViewControllerDidLike;
- (void) detailViewControllerDidUnlike;
- (void) detailViewControllerDidDislike;

@end
```

**DetailViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction) changeLikedSwitch: (id) sender
{
    UISwitch *likedSwitch = (UISwitch *) sender;
    if ([likedSwitch isOn]) {
        [_selectedQuote setIsLiked: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]];
        [self.delegate detailViewControllerDidLike];
    } else {
        [_selectedQuote setIsLiked: [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO]];
        [self.delegate detailViewControllerDidUnlike];
    }

    NSError *error;
    if (![[[CDManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext] save:&error]) NSLog(@"Saving changes failed: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}

- (IBAction) changeDislikedSwitch: (id) sender
{
    UISwitch *dislikedSwitch = (UISwitch *) sender;
    if ([dislikedSwitch isOn]) {
        [_selectedQuote setIsDisliked: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]];
        [self.delegate detailViewControllerDidDislike];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
    } else {
        [_selectedQuote setIsDisliked: [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO]];
    }

    NSError *error;
    if (![[[CDManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext] save:&error]) NSLog(@"Saving changes failed: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
```

**TableViewController.h Interface line:**

```
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, DetailViewControllerDelegate>
```

**TableViewController.m**

```
- (void) detailViewControllerDidLike
{
    NSLog(@"detailViewControllerDidLike!");
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void) detailViewControllerDidUnlike
{
    NSLog(@"detailViewControllerDidUnlike!");
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void) detailViewControllerDidDislike
{
    NSLog(@"detailViewControllerDidDislike!");
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

None of these methods are called. I'm trying to work out whether it's because I haven't set the delegate, but I don't understand how I can do that. There isn't an instance of my `DetailViewController` in my `TableViewController`, so how am I supposed to set one of its properties? Isn't the whole point of having a delegate that I don't need to create a concrete link between the classes? Very, very confused here.

Comment: How you are calling DetailViewController class from TableViewController ?

Comment: I'm using `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: Yes check as Levi suggested.

Comment: is self.delegate in detailviewcontroller referring the instance of tableviewcontroller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do need to set the delegate, for delegate methods to be called.

You must have a class that creates both the TableViewController and the DetailViewController? when they are created you would call

`[myDetailViewControllerObject setDelegate:myTableViewControllerObject];`

to set the delegate. This is assuming you've defined a delegate property in DetailViewController with

```
@property (readwrite, weak) id<DetailViewcontrollerDelegate> delegate;
```

A further explanation of delegates:

The point of a delegate is so that you don't need a specific type of object, you only need an object that implements the protocol. There still needs to be a connection between the delegate and the "delegator". If you want no concrete connection, then you would want to use an NSNotification, which is very much a "shout into the ether, and hope something is listening" method of communication.

In this case, a delegate is the correct thing to use. Delegates should be for one-to-one relationships, NSNotification are best used for one-to-N type relationships, where N can be 0 or more.

Comment: I thought the entire point of a delegate was that you didn't need a concrete link between the classes. That a delegate would just pick up on those messages wherever they're sent from?

Comment: I've edited my answer to give a further explanation of the use of delegates

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to set the delegate. In the `prepareForSegue` you write:

myDetailController.delegate = self;

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure about following things for delegate.

Creating Property

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id < SettingsViewControllerDelegate > delegate;
```

Synthesize it but do not release it

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

Set delegate on your object.

```
settingsViewController.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a delegate for DetailViewControllerDelegate in your TableViewController.h:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
@property (retain, nonatomic) id <DetailViewControllerDelegate>delegate;
```

Then in TableViewController.m:

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

Now call your delegate method as:

```
[delegate detailViewControllerDidLike];
```

Most important: Where you are adding TableViewController in your main view, don't forget to write:

```
taleViewControllerInstanceName.delegate=self;
```